# dynamic jquery accordion not working in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, jquery-ui-accordion

I have requirement when I am creating accordion dynamically. I have a list using which, i will filter the record and create accordion based on selected date. Below is the code for accordion

```
<div id="accordion" class="accordion" style="margin-top:20px;" class="div-shadow col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <template v-for="invGroup in invGroupTotals">
                    <label>{{invGroup.Group}}<span style="float:right; font-size:12px" v-if="invGroup.DiffTotal === 0 && invGroup.DiffAmtTotal === zero" class="text-success"> No Difference </span><span class="text-danger" style="float:right; font-size:12px" v-else>Difference Count {{invGroup.DiffTotal}} , Amount ${{invGroup.DiffAmtTotal}}</span></label>
                <div style="text-align: center; background-color: white; overflow-y:auto;" >
                <table cellpadding="10" style="border-style: solid; border-color: Gray; border-collapse: separate;border-spacing: 2px" class="table tableStyle col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <tr>
                      <th v-for="column in weeklyReconcileGridColumns">{{column}}</th>
                    </tr>
                    <template  v-for="item in weeklyReconcileList">
                    <tr  v-if="invGroup.Group === item.UPCGroup">
                      <td >{{item.UPCID}}</td>
                      <td class="text-left" v-on:click="showItemHistory(item.UPCID, item.UPCDesc)"><a href="#">{{item.UPCDesc}}</a></td>
                      <td >{{item.SystemBOH}}</td>
                      <td >{{item.CurrentWeekBOH}}</td>
                      <td >{{item.Diffrence}}</td>
                      <td >{{parseFloat(item.TotalSalesAmount).toFixed(2)}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </template>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center" colspan="2"> Total</td>
                        <td> {{invGroup.SysTotal}}</td>
                        <td> {{invGroup.CountedTotal}}</td>
                        <td> {{invGroup.DiffTotal}}</td>
                        <td> {{invGroup.DiffAmtTotal}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
```

The problem is, suppose on the first load 2 accordion is shown. When changed the date there are three accordion then the accordion style is not applied in third one. I am calling the accordion in Updated Hook as shown below.

updated: function () {
      $("#accordion").accordion();}

Could you please suggest how can i correct the issue. thanks in advance.

Comment: Try wrapping the $("#accordion").accordion() inside nextTick.       updated: function () {this.$nextTick(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion()
      })}

Comment: No this is not working, I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I made it working by refreshing the accordion. The only thing we need to take care is refreshing after accordion is instantiated. check other methods click [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-destroy).

Comment: I am facing a problem, since i also have textbox in the accordion content, when entering any value the accordion is getting refreshed and is closed. Plz suggest a solution.

Comment: can you try calling the $("#accordion").accordion() whenever a particular data object changes rather than inside the update hook.